# Updating a column with maximum matches from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, match

I have two tables let’s say A & B and would like to update the column of Status in table A with maximum matches from the column Scores in table B by comparing the 'Topics' of two tables.

I am using the script shown here, but it's taking a really long time so I'd appreciate it if somebody could provide an alternative / better and faster option/script

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET status = (SELECT max(scores) 
                        FROM tableB
                        WHERE tableB.topics = tableA.topics)
```

Comment: is `id` in `tableB` properly indexed?

Comment: not really, it's a mixed data where the "topics" are repeated multiple times with different scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
UPDATE tableA 
    SET status = (SELECT max(scores) 
                  FROM tableB
                  WHERE tableB.topics = tableA.topics
                 );
```

The only index you need is on `tableB(topics, scores)`.

If you like, you can rewrite this as an aggregation, which looks like this:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET status = b.max_scores
    FROM (SELECT b.topic, MAX(scores) as max_scores
          FROM tableB b
          GROUP BY b.topic
         ) b
    WHERE b.topic = a.topic;
```

Note that this is subtly different from your query.  If there are topics in `A` that are not in `B`, then this will not update those rows.  I do not know if that is desirable.

If many rows in `A` have the same `topic`, then pre-aggregating could be significantly faster than the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating proper indexes for each column involved and you should be fine, e.g:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tableb_topics_scores ON tableb (topics,scores);
```

An alternative to your query is to apply the aggregate function `max()` in a way that it only has to be executed once, but I doubt it will speed things up:

```
UPDATE tablea a SET status = j.max_scores
FROM (SELECT a.topics,max(b.scores) AS max_scores 
      FROM tablea a
      JOIN tableb b ON a.topics = b.topics
      GROUP BY a.topics) j
WHERE a.topics = j.topics;
```